# Links corrupt on send

Tags: issues, links

I use our CiviCRM database to send out mailings to members.
The mailings contain links to articles on our website.
It has worked well for years but now when I press 'Send' the links in the email corrupt and reference a CiviCRM link instead of the website link so recipients can't access it. For a while I didn't notice because of course when I click the link myself in the copy I receive, it opens, and CiviCRM doesn't give an alert or warning.

Any idea what's happening and how I can fix it? (Remember I'm not an expert!)

Answer (score 2):

When you create a mailing with CiviMail, there's an option:

> Track Click Throughs
>
> Track the number of times recipients click each link in this mailing.
>
> NOTE: When this feature is enabled, all links in the message body will
>   be automatically re-written to route through your CiviCRM server prior
>   to redirecting to the target page.

Perhaps you have enabled this option? This wouldn't normally prevent the links from working, however.

Are the links in the email something like, http://mysite.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=123&qid=12345 ? If so, that is normal when tracking click throughs is enabled.

What happens when a user clicks on one of the links?

Which CiviCRM version and CMS (Drupal, Wordpress or Joomla) are you using?

Comment: What happens is that the link which should be to our website is now saying something like 192.168.1.4/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/… - not like yours. When I click on that it takes me to our civi program and shows me the page I wanted on the website, but when other people click on it they see nothing because they're not authorised to access our Civi program.

Comment: Your link seems to be like mine except for having 192.168.1.4 in place of a hostname. 192.168.1.4 is a private IP address, meaning it can only be accessed from within your local network. Two solutions: either turn off "Track Click Throughs" on future mailings, or talk to your network administrator, refer them to this post and ask if external access can be configured for /sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php . You may also want access to open.php in the same location, to track people opening the emails.

Comment: Thanks - that looks plausible - I've passed it on to the IT guys (who we buy in, so I try not to use them too much!) and we'll have a play with it later to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for you but not for anonymous users, it is likely connected to a permission problem either caused by CiviCRM/your CMS or your server set up. Did you change anything on your set up lately e.g. put your install behind a VPN?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly. What happens is that the link which should be to our website is now saying something like http://192.168.1.4/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=473&qid=204189 - when I click on that it takes me to our civi program and shows me the page I wanted on the website, but when other people click on it they see nothing because they're not authorised to access our program.